# Python ,Tkinter, Mac - I am using a text box and it works fine until I click on the menubar(edit, file buttons) text is disabled

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Python ,Tkinter, Mac - I am using a text box and it works fine until I click on the menubar(edit, file buttons) text is disabled I cannot write on the text box anymore. so when I first run the code I can start writing text in the textbook but then when I click on the menu bar and click away and back on the text box. this problem is only on Mac my team member uses windows 10 and works fine for him.
help appreciated thanks
(Im a new developer so I am still learning basics thanks)

```
from cProfile import label
from cgitb import text
from tkinter import *



#main window
gui = Tk()
gui.configure(bg='#FDF4A7')
gui.geometry('225x250')
gui.overrideredirect(True)
gui.resizable(True, True)


def kill():
    gui.destroy()
    return None


def newnote():
     text_box.configure(state='normal')


def Cut(e):
    global selected
    if gui.selection_get():
        selected = gui.selection_get()
        text.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")


topMenu = Menu(gui)
gui.config(menu=topMenu)



# Create submenus and cascade them to top level menu
submenu1 = Menu(topMenu)
topMenu.add_cascade(menu=submenu1, label="File")
submenu1.add_command(label="Quit", command=kill)
submenu1.add_command(label="New Note", command=newnote)

# Create nested menus
nestedMenu = Menu(submenu1)
submenu1.add_cascade(menu=nestedMenu, label='Nested Menu')
nestedMenu.add_command(label="Nested command 1") 

# Create edit menus 
editMenu = Menu(topMenu)
topMenu.add_cascade(menu=editMenu, label="Edit")
editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", command="Cut")
editMenu.add_command(label="Copy",)
editMenu.add_command(label="Paste",)

title_bar = Frame(
    gui,
    bg='#FDF5A7',
    relief="raised",
    bd=0
)
title_bar.pack(
    expand = 1,
    fill = X,
)

title_label = Label(
    title_bar,
    text="Sticky Notes",
    bg='darkgreen',
    fg='white',
)

title_label.pack(
    side = LEFT,
    pady = 0,
)


text_box = Text(
    gui,
    bg='#FDF5A7',
    fg='black',
    height='10000',
    width='10000',
    padx='10',
    pady='10'
    
)

text_box.pack(
    expand = True,
)

text_box.configure(state='normal')
text_box.config(highlightthickness = 0, borderwidth = 0)

#main code
gui.mainloop()
#
```